# Cypress Variable undefined

Tags: variables, automation, cypress

I am trying to set a variable to then use later on in an assert. I want to verify a date on one page is the same on another page. I have the below;

```
cy.get("#due > div > div > div > input").then(($dueDatePicker) => {
  const dueDate = $dueDatePicker.text();
  cy.log(dueDate);
});
```

I then have the below assert later on in the test;

```
cy.get("#content > div > section.content.mtm10 > div.row > div > div > div.box-body").contains(dueDate);
```

However Cypress tells me dueDate is undefined in the Assert.

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a scoping issue with where you are defining the variable. There are a few ways to get around this.

The first would be to declare the variable outside of the Cypress chain.

```js
let dueDate = ''
cy.get('foo')
  .then(($el) => {
    dueDate = $el.text()
  })
  .get('bar').contains(dueDate);
```

You could also return the value from the `.then()`.

```js
cy.get('foo')
  .then(($el) => {
    return $el.text();
  })
  .then((dueDate) => {
    cy.get('bar').contains(dueDate);
  })
```

I'd recommend Filip Hric's [blogpost on Cypress variables](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-variables) for more information on understanding how the variables/scopes/timing all work together.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using the value later ***in the same test***, an [alias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Elements) is the preferred way to store a result for a later assertion

```js
cy.get("#due > div > div > div > input")
  .invoke('text') 
  .as('dueDate')

...

cy.get('@dueDate').then(dueDate => {
  cy.get("#content > div > section.content.mtm10 > div.row > div > div > div.box-body")
    .contains(dueDate)
})
```